# jQuery transparent image description slide animation on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Ok here we go, i have this fiddle for you:

### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KK57/)

It doesn't work as expected, so i'll describe what i need and what the problems are. The goal is a sliding description when hovering the box.

Here is what i want, and ***everything which does not work is emphasized***:

- Every box has an image, a title and a description. Everything except the description is visible.
- When the mouse is over a box, the title/description slides to the ***half height of the box***, which makes the description visible. ***The overall height of the box does not change.***
- ***The image should be invisible outside the bounds of the box***.
- ***The animation shouldn't "jump" to the end, when moving the mouse fast in and out.***

Can you help me?

Comment: In Google Chrome the image that you want to be invisible is already invisible, please check.

Comment: Google Chrome Linux here, and it is visible

Comment: Hmm.. That's where it get tricky and annoying at the same time. Don't have Linux installed at the moment. Good luck.

Comment: I need some pointers why the demonstration does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, not sure but i think it's your answer.

I am putting fiddle link [click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krishna_aim24/CBEmW/1/)

And JS code :

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('.box').hover(function() {
        var _tst = this;
        jQuery(this).find(".text").animate({
        "height": jQuery(_tst).find(".text").height() + jQuery(_tst).find(".desc").height()
    }, {
        duration: 600,
        queue: false
    });
    jQuery(this).find(".img").animate({
        "top": -jQuery(_tst).find(".desc").height()
    }, {
        duration: 600,
        queue: false
    });
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".text").animate({
        "height": "30px"
    }, {
        duration: 600,
        queue: false
    });
    jQuery(this).find(".img").animate({
        "top": 0
    }, {
        duration: 600,
        queue: false
    });
});
```

});​

and did some css changes.
[Click here to see the changes](http://jsfiddle.net/krishna_aim24/CBEmW/1/)